# Developing An iOS SDK for a REST API

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, api, sdk

I've been grappling with this for a few days now, and can't seem to figure out how to best structure this.  I'm by no means an expert with Objective C.

We have developed a RESTful API to our Drupal application, and we currently have an iOS app out in the App Store that's using ASIHTTPRequest to connect to it.  However, as some of you may know, it's no longer being supported. So we decided to transition over to AFNetworking and would like to build it in such a way that we can open source it as a library to use with our API.

Our current application is using CoreData and stores all data coming in to a SQLite database.  The workflow at the moment looks something like this:

Get Request 
Receive JSON
Parse and map JSON to CoreData NSManagedObject
Save Context

I have several questions on what path you guys would suggest for me to open source as a library.

Just to give a rough overview:

We have Members, Groups, Events, Messages (at its simplest).

There are several ways I've been thinking of going about this:

**Add the AFNetworking api calls and the parsing / mapping methods to the NSManagedObject**

I like this concept, but I'm not sure if it makes sense.  Core data schema then becomes the schema to the API and that's wonderful.  But my concern is - what if other developers using this don't want to use core data in their app? On top of that, I'm not sure how it would look with methods that return more than one instance.  For example if I have an NSManagedObject Group, where do I put the call to get an index of groups? Also, are we then locking someone into a specific core data model, and is that a good thing?

**Have separate objects that know how to retrieve their own data from an API, parse it to their own properties, and then somewhere out of the public library do the mapping to the NSManaged Objects**

This way sounds good too, but then I have very similar objects with very similar properties.

**Categories**

I read something up here where I can use a category to add methods
[add additional properties to NSManagedObject with secondary .h .m files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900155/add-additional-properties-to-nsmanagedobject-with-secondary-h-m-files)
I'm not sure if that even makes sense.

**An API Class, A Core Data Class, and mapper classes.**

Definitely messy.

**Better suggestions welcome!**

I've tried to look at some other examples, but I don't think I have enough Objective C knowledge to dissect them properly.

The main goals are:

Abstract to a request library that's re-usable in other apps.
Enforcing a schema for objects is a plus
Don't lock people into a CoreData model or using CoreData at all if they don't want to.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You should create your own model classes if you are trying to enforce your schema.  This can be done by just subclass NSObject (or anything that makes sense), or going with the Core Data/NSManagedObject Route.  If you do that, just include the needed files.

Personally, I would manage the server calls separately. Taking a look at the Facebook SDK 3.0 may give you some help.  Basically create one or multiple classes that will handle your server calls, parse the information, and pass it back to a delegate/block in way that makes sense for your user.

Here you can return your custom objects (or arrays of them, etc.)  You can build this all on top of any networking layer.  I am a fan of AFNetworking, but any will work. Just include that code needed in a subproject/submodule/etc.  Just make sure to give credit to all libs you use.

Another option would be to create a framework or static library that wraps this all together and does not allow other developers to change your internal code.  Hope this is a start.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the response! I just want to clarify a few things up: I already do have a core data schema, so I can extend NSManagedObjects to enforce the schema on the API.  But you're recommending to separate classes that make the API calls, parse the data and return something that extends NS Object.  Would it be possible for me to flip that and extend what the API call classes return to be a managed object? Sorry I might've missed a lot of points here.  I read this a few times and couldn't particularly understand. Would u mind breaking it down a little bit (for a n00b :)

Comment: Sat on this for a bit and I think its starting to make sense. Basically, you're saying to create several models - group, message, user, etc.  And then have a controller / controllers that makes the api calls, parsers, and populates these models, and then returns them.  And then seed the NSManagedObjects and populate them with data from these objects based on models. Is that right?